# Adding variables to URl on php GET request

Tags: php, get

i am trying to add too variable on a URL for me to make a php GET request.

```
   $varible1 = 'bar';
   $variable2 = 'foo';

   curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://example.com/<?php echo $variable1 ?>/amount/<?php echo $variable2 ?>,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request'
));
```

i can see by the colour formatting of my text editor that it is wrong please help

Comment: Look at the `CURLOPT_URL`. Concatenate `$variable1` and `$variable2`, you already in PHP.

Comment: Well, presumably, you're already in a php file, so you don't need to do `<?php ...`. Just concatenate the parts of the URL. Also, you're failing to close the URL in a single quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using " instead of ', then you can insert variables easily.

For example

```
CURLOPT_URL => "https://example.com/$variable1/amount/$variable2";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use string concatenation  (avoiding the   because seems you are in a php array )

```
CURLOPT_URL => 'https://example.com/' . $variable1 '/amount/' .  $variable2 ,
```